# Enable Raspberry Pi's internal pull-up resistors?

Tags: android-things

Is there a way to enable Raspberry Pi's internal pull-up resistors using Android Things?

EDIT: I filed a feature request -> https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233630

Comment: be nice if you added some reference documentation. Also maybe some things you have already tried, or an example of the reasoning why you want to do this.

Comment: The API in the current developer preview does not support this. You may file a feature request if you would like to see this behavior in a future release: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Things%20feature%20request

Comment: Thanks @Devunwired. I'll file a feature request :)

Comment: As far as a Java API I haven't seen anything. Probably not what you're looking for, but I would guess you can do that by either `adb shell` and command line or compiling and running utilities such as bcm3825 library or wiringPi. So far everything I'm learning about Ubuntu +  Raspberry pi is applying nicely to Android Things + Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now available through the android things console:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As of current release ([DP2](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html#developer_preview_2)), there is no Peripheral I/O API to dynamically configure pull/down resistor on Android Things.

However has pointed in the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html#raspberry_pi_1) and the [BCM2835 documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf), the Raspberry Pi 3 has internal pull-up (3.3V) resistor configured by default on the following pins, when configured as input with `Gpio.setDirection`:

- BCM4
- BCM5
- BCM6

Comment: Seems that these resistors are not activated by default though. I've managed to get these pins working only after activating them through shell command: `echo UP > /sys/class/pinctrl/BCM5/resistor` as described [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37135220#comment4)

Comment: In my testing on DP7, there are no longer internal pull-up resistors on 4,5,6 :(

Comment: `echo UP > /sys/class/pinctrl/BCM5/resistor` still works on BCM5 though!

Answer (score -4):

First you should read [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-up_resistor!) for base knowlege.Pull-up resistors is hardware, it make uncertain voltage to 1 or 0 for pin!

Comment: I know is hardware. Raspberry Pi has built-in pull-up resistors that can be activated through software: [read this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39313/do-all-gpio-pins-have-a-internal-pull-up-pull-down-resistors) or [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/physical-computing-guide/pull_up_down/)